# html/css scaling images to mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

ok so im trying to get my background image to scale properly from desktop to mobile the code im using is:

CSS

```
@media (max-width:500px){
#homepage{
padding-right: 5%;
padding-bottom: 80px;
position: relative;
background-size: cover ;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(../img/bg-mobile.jpg);
height: 100%;
 }
}
```

with that code the image size displaying on mobile is about 35x65px ( the image "bg-mobile" is 337width X 667height as ive found that css code should work, but its not could someone please help me ( sorry i dont know how more specific i can be )

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle with the html and the css. 
I think I can help you with this.

Comment: Maybe there is another CSS rule that is changing the behavior of the background image. As Brain already said, please provide a JS Fiddle or something similar to get more context

Comment: js fiddler wasnt able to load on my pc, ive uploaded the site rar file to google drive and is able to be downloaded ( i hope thats ok) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxQmwgeZ27_0alZlYWlaeVp1QWM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: change had no effect :(, thanks for the fast response

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be a better idea to scale the image's resolution proportionally to itself.

`HTML`:

```
<div class="img_resz">
    <img src="img.jpg">
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
.img_resz img 
{
    width: 50%;
}
```